# Changing document Signature (magic numbers)

Tags: windows, computer-forensics

For my project I'm experimenting with disguising the content of a file and thought a good way to do this would be to change the document signature (magic numbers). I think in order to do this I need to change the starting x bytes of the hex but am not sure if this is possible? I've tried looking at the file I want to change in various hex viewers such as autopsy but it strips back all the metadata and only shows the content of that file and the corresponding hex. My question is it possible to change the signature and if so what is the best way to go about it? Any program recommendations?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to change arbitrary bytes of any file as long as you have sufficient privileges. But the question is weird and asking for program recommendations is not going to be well-received here. What is your actual objective? Would it be served by employing cryptography or steganography?

Comment: Sorry for the poor structure, first post and didn't really explain myself well.

I'm a student and am just trying trying to demonstrate how someone might try to hide something on a computer. An alternative would be to encrypt but I thought I would try to disguise the file so i guess steganography? By this I mean were someone to put it into say autopsy and it was a JPEG but id changed the signature I want the MIME type to list as what I changed it to but still be able to view the content. I don't need a program,just confirmation that the only aspect I need to change are those first few bytes?

Comment: By "still be able to view the content", do you mean they can still view the original jpeg in an image viewer even after you corrupted the header to remove the jpeg signature? For example, if you changed the MIME type to pdf, do you still want the original image to open in mspaint?

Comment: I want to edit the header in such a way that any non forensic tool can't open the file. So I don't want paint to be able to open it but I would still want to see the content in autopsy?